# What hypothesis test should I use to test if a binary variable is dependent on an ordinal value?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, categorical-data, ordinal-data, binary-data

I have a number of finishes in football which are labeled either goal or miss. For each shot I know the standings in the game at the time of the shot, which I use to calculate `gamestate` for the shooting team (1 = leading, 0 = tied, -1 = trailing). I have calculated the conversion rate for each value of `gamestate`.

I want to test if the outcome is dependent on `gamestate` and would like to reject the hypothesis that the outcome of a shot is not dependent on `gamestate`.

**Question:** Does this makes sense? What test should I use?

```
total shots: 30331
goals: 3674
conversion: 12.11 %

#for each gamestate
   shots  conv_rate  goals   Gamestate
0   8339  0.111164    927     -1
1  14032  0.115522   1621      0
2   7960  0.141457   1126      1
```

Below is the data uncategorized:

```
    shots  conv_rate  goals    Gamestate
0       6  0.166667      1         -7
1      10  0.000000      0         -6
2      24  0.166667      4         -5
3     140  0.121429     17         -4
4     535  0.104673     56         -3
5    1977  0.109762    217         -2
6    5647  0.111918    632         -1
7   14032  0.115522   1621          0
8    5252  0.136519    717          1
9    1849  0.149270    276          2
10    605  0.157025     95          3
11    163  0.165644     27          4
12     60  0.133333      8          5
13     18  0.166667      3          6
14     13  0.000000      0          7
```

Comment: Why not just use the prior gamestates directly instead of categorizing them first?

Comment: @gung Since the number of shots is low for "extreme" gamestates the conversion rates vary a lot. The rationale behind gamestate is that a leading team puts more effort in defending than attacking and vice versa, so it should not really matter if its 1 or 2 etc. I update my question to also include the data without categorizing.

Comment: Is it reasonable to assume that gamestate is equal-interval? Ie, that the amount of improvement from, say, -3 to -2 is the same as the amount of improvement from, say, 5 to 6?

Comment: @gung At trailing by -1 its still fairly probably you could draw or win the game, but at -4 its likely not that much time left and you have kind of given up, so if 5 its or 6 does not matter. But i would say its mostly up to the tactics of a team, when leading by 2 goals you might chose to secure that lead and put all effort on defending while other teams might keep attacking all through the game.

Comment: Note for when you might publish papers in the future: the English pronoun "I" is _always_ capitalized (even when it is in the middle of a sentence).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> would like to reject the hypothesis that the outcome of a shot is not dependent on the gamestate.

So we want to see if difference in goals (goals-to-shots rather) is independent of gamestat. Because this is categorical data, the obvious test is $Pearson's\ \chi^2$. Using R:

```
football <- matrix(c(8339,927,14032,1621,7960,1126), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
rownames(football) <- c("-1", "0", "1")
colnames(football) <- c("shots", "goals")
> football
   shots goals
-1  8339   927
0  14032  1621
1   7960  1126
```

The test:

```
> chisq.test(football)

    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  football
X-squared = 33.207, df = 2, p-value = 6.153e-08
```

The test has very high significance ($p<0.001$) and you can reject your $H_0$.

Comment: Thank you! 
A follow up question: Would you say it makes more sense to do chi square test of independece like this than a goodness of fit to an uniform distribution? Do the tests complement each other or make each other redundant? 
I want to argue for that gamestate is a useful feature in a logistic regression model.

Comment: Another follow-up question: Shouldn't I be using goals and misses instead of goals and shots?

Comment: @KarlAnka 1) goodness of fit is not a specific test, but a family. Chi sq is a goodness of fit that checks of the data is uniformly distributed (in your case, it is not). 2) argue away. Just remember that a randomly sliced interval data can be statistically significant without being theoretically reasonable. So just make sure to explain the WHY (see gung's comment above). 3) Yes you should. I one should not contain the other. It seems that it will be significant nonetheless.